# Cuztomizing en_US layout on a non-en_US keyboard (Windows 10)

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, international

I use an en_US keyboard layout on a physical SWE/FI keyboard.

For reference:
SWE/FI
[image: SWE/FI]

en_US
[image: en_US]
*(image credit Wikipedia CC BY-SA 3.0)*

Everything works fine. However, there is one extra key next to the LSHIFT button.

On my Windows machine, this key acts as a duplicate of the \| -key next to ENTER.
On Linux (Arch) this key acts the way it does in the SWE/FI layout; as its own <> key.

I vastly prefer the Linux configuration. Is there a way to duplicate this on Windows, i.e. rebinding the key without altering how the other \| -key (the one next to ENTER) works?

I'm familiar with Autohotkey. Problem is I don't know how to differentiate between the two keys.

Comment: What does UK English do? At least it's expecting the extra key to be there.

Comment: UK English just uses the UK English layout as it's physically identical to SWE/FI. However, its placement of special character differs from en_US which is the reason I use en_US.

Comment: Have you tried [Keyboard Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) from PowerToys?

Comment: AutoHotkey can detect and display key evens: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Input.htm, and https://superuser.com/questions/337947/how-can-i-see-all-keypresses-on-the-keyboard . Another tool, online via javascript, is https://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html . +1 for a clearly stated and illustrated question!

Comment: Neither AHK nor JavaScript differentiates between the two physical keys, since Windows treats them as duplicates of each other. Powertools seems to be able to differentiate between the two keys, however the desired functionality does not show up when en_US layout is selected, probably because it isn't normally present in en_US. With FIN/SWE layout selected the <> button shows up, but trying to remap \ to it I get a "cannot remap key to itself" error.

Comment: To elaborate: which layout I have enabled when I click on the dropdown menu decides whether I see two \ keys or a < key and a ' key (the two physical keys that rebind to \ when switching layouts). However, even though the character displayed is different, trying to pick \ and < (precisely what I want to do) causes a "cannot remap key to itself".

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to find out with AutoHotkey what a given key is sending:

- Run any AutoHotkey script
- Right-click the "H" icon and select "Open"
- Select menu *View > Key history and script info*
- Press your key
- Press F5 to refresh the display.

You will see at the bottom of the screen the details of this key
followed by F5.

The key might have a known AutoHotkey name, and you
will find it under the "Key" column.

If this column is empty, see the code under "SC". If the code is
for example `03F`, then you can refer to the key as `SC03F`
inside a AutoHotkey script.

Comment: Because the Windows implementation of the en_US layout treats these two physical buttons as the same button, they both show up identical in the AutoHotkey history.

Comment: The code is the key-code that is sent by the keyboard. If for your keyboard the two keys are identical, there is a problem.

Comment: Did you read the question before answering? What you are telling me is more or less the premise of the question.

Comment: If your results from my answer are that your keyboard generates exactly the same key-codes for both keys, then you have narrowed the problem to the keyboard itself, either hardware or firmware. In that respect, there is no solution possible in software, and probably also not in hardware either.

Comment: I have not narrowed down anything. I described all this in the question which you apparently did not read. What your answer has told me is the premise to the question I posed, and what I had already done (and mentioned doing) before asking the question.

Comment: Your premise that the problem is with Windows is just wrong. AHK gets the key-code as sent by the keyboard, but you insist otherwise. Nobody can help if you ignore us. Although in this case the advice is to give up or get another keyboard  ...